# Hadoop YARN: How to manage I/O

Tags: hadoop, io, hadoop-yarn

As far as I know Hadoop YARN can only manage CPUs and memory (and with Hadoop 3.0 devices like FPGA / GPUs. However, I would like to manage I/O.

Is there a option I am missing?
What possibilities are available to manage I/O on YARN?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop doesn't explicitly support management of I/O.  The closest thing you can get is probably MapReduce counters where you can track bytes read, and bytes written.  If you want to manage it, you'd have to track these externally possibly with some governance middleware.